# How to detect file input closing in angular?

Tags: angular

I need to detect the file input dialog once i try to close without any change, but i can't do in angular , i found the solution for the problem but using javascript only and i tried to convert to angular code but its not working properly.

I tried to convert the js code to angular.

```
 @ViewChild('file') file: ElementRef;
 constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {}
```

I use the document object of js like the above.

After file input is clicked it execute the onClick function below.

```
onClick() {
console.log('On Click');
this.document.body.onfocus = this.test();
}
test() {
console.log(this.selectedFile);
if (this.selectedFile != null) {
  if (this.selectedFile.length) {
    alert('ROAR! FILES!');
  } else {
    alert('*empty wheeze*');
  }
}
this.document.body.onfocus = null;
}

you can get the javascript version of code from here ` 
http://jsfiddle.net/Shiboe/yuK3r/6/`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Shiboe/yuK3r/6/

I need this code works for Angular 4, help me out.

Comment: can you please share your angular code ?

Comment: I added my code , pls check now

Comment: You can take a look also on my answer on a similar issue: stackoverflow.com/a/77433739/6295493

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `template reference variable` for this purpose. try this code (in app.component.html):

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileSelected($event)" style='display:none' #godzilla>
<button (click)="godzilla.click()">mech-godzilla</button>
```

and in component.ts:

```
fileSelected(event){
   console.log('file selected');
}
```

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hello-world-f9y1r6)

Comment: I need to detect the file dialog close event , but it just open the dialog bro, can you pls check again.

Comment: i actually just converted your js code to angular, i will look further for this function as well

Comment: @SandyKrish you only want to check file select case or cancel as well?

Comment: @Mustahsan this code will just open the file choosen dialog.

Comment: @Mustahsan cancel as well (if the file dialog is closed without any selection , then i need to execute some function call thats why am asking)

Comment: @SandyKrish actually file close event is not exposed to the browser so we cannot detect it directly, you need to have some workaround on event binding to the document.body

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service that tracks the focus event on your app.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FocusTrackingService {
  private appFocusSubject = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() {
    this.setupFocusListener();
  }

  private setupFocusListener() {
    window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
      this.appFocusSubject.next(true);
    });
  }

  getAppFocusObservable(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.appFocusSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Then in your component where you're opening the dialog you can subscribe to that service.

```
@ViewChild('YourFileInputIdGoesHere') fileInput!: ElementRef;
private filePickerHasOpened: boolean = false;

constructor(private focusTrackingService: FocusTrackingService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.focusTrackingService.getAppFocusObservable().subscribe((isInFocus) => {
    // If we regain focus on our app and our dialog has been opened
    if (isInFocus && this.filePickerHasOpened) {
      this.filePickerHasOpened = false;
      // Do stuff
    }
  });
}

openFileDialog(): void {
    this.filePickerHasOpened = true;
    this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
}
```